# Mapping C function to Call Stack

Tags: c, function, stack, callstack

I have been reading about Call Stack and how operating systems store functions data on the stack. All the reading so far I have done ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html), [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391) and [here](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/ctoassemblytranslation.htm#.VPiMvXX0-00)) says something similar about how function is stored on the stack. But I tried to apply that to a sample C program with two functions, just to see how these data are stored, but the results I get is inconsistent with all I have been reading so far. I might be interpreting the data wrongly, so I was hoping somebody could make some clarifications.

## PROBLEM

*I am working on buffer overflow examples, and how to exploit them*

So as far that I have understood, when I call a function (e.g: func1(int a)), what the system does is, allocate space for parameters (8bytes for integer in our example) allocate space and save RETURN address of the calling function . Then it will save base pointer (EBP), after that it will allocate space for local variables( local v1, local v2....) and then the rest of data. In my example I have two local variables (char buff[4](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/ctoassemblytranslation.htm#.VPiMvXX0-00) and char *ptr). which means there will be 8 bytes of space allocated.  based on my assumptions, I thought to get to RETURN address I only need to write 12 bytes of data in buffer, which would result in overwriting the RETURN address( and I would exploit that). 12bytes =  4 bytes of data buff + 4 bytes of data on EBP, and then the last 4 bytes should be the address that I would want to write in place of current RETURN address. BUT, so far I had to pass 16bytes of data to do so. I don't understand where the extra 4 bytes of data are coming from. I used gdb(i am not very proficient in it )to find out, but I couldn't. Am I missing to count for something that is being added on the stack? or is it that the local variables are added in reverse order (*s pointer first, and buff second)?

## CODE

```
char *func1(int n){
    char buff[4];
    char *ptr = malloc(n+1);
    fgets(ptr,n+1,stdin);
    strncpy(buff,ptr,n+1);
    return ptr;

}
```

Comment: Note that it's not the OS that does all of this with the stack, it's your own program through the machine code your compiler generated.

Comment: You should know that the C specification doesn't actually mentions a "stack", how functions are called and how arguments and local variables are stored is up to the implementation. And here's the kicker: Each compiler may do it a little bit different. Also, what you're doing is exploiting undefined behavior, and make one little mistake and the behavior will be, well, undefined.

Comment: thanks, I am just learning about it, so was trying to somehow understand how it all works

Comment: Note that stack frames are probably aligned to 16 byte boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the missing data is the 'n', which is also on the stack.

Also, note that the compiler has no obligation to put the memory of 'buff' before your 'ptr', so you may also have to overwrite ptr in some cases.

Also, in many cases temporary variables are also computed on the stack, so your n+1 may also implicitly add some stack space.  I imagine this code would use a different amount of stack space, for example, if optimizations were turned on/off.

A simpler example for this (as a test), might be to pass the ptr into the function, and do something like:

```
char buf[1];
strcpy(buf, ptr);
```